# Add function to Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, parametric-functions

I have a `Manipulate` plot and want to add another function, in addition to the existing `a` and `e`. The existing code is as follows:

```
SetOptions[Plot, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12, Bold}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], ImageSize -> Medium]; 

Constants

au = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]]; 
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]]; 
Qpr = 1; 
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]]; 
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]]; 
Msun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]]; 
G = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], 
     ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/"Kilograms"^2]]; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
Myr = year*10^6; 
Gyr = year*10^9; 
Mwd = 0.6*Msun; 
Cst = 1.27; 
U = 1*10^17; 

Functions

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1); 
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]); 

Radiative Drag

RDdadtRρa = -((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(c^2*(16*Pi*2000*Rast*a[t]*(1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2)))); 
RDdedtRρa = -((15*L[t]*e[t])/(c^2*(32*Pi*Rast*2000*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2]))); 

RDsolRρa = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][a][t] == RDdadtRρa, 
     Derivative[1][e][t] == RDdedtRρa, a[0] == a0, e[0] == 3/10}, {a, e}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
    {Rast, ρ, a0}]; 

fRDticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1/Myr}], Automatic}}; 

Manipulate[Plot[RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[func]][t], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks], 
  {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{ρ, 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 3, 20, 0.2, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

I want to add a further plot, which is defined as: `q=a(1-e)`, where `a` and `e` are already plotted. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can define `q[a_,e_]:=a (1-e)` outside `Manipulate[...]` and then insert the `q[a,e]` function into `Manipulate`. This would normally work.

Comment: I've defined the function `Papsis` in the above code, but I don't know how to add it into my current `Manipulate` function and have another tab, in addition to `a` and `e` on the plot which shows `Papsis` plotted. Sorry I'm relatively new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I introduced the function `fun` and `TrackedSymbols-{..}` as well as `{{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}` into the `Manipulate`. The rest is the same. The changed `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 fun[sel_, t_] := 
  Switch[sel, 1, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
   RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t], 3, 
   RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][
     t] (1 - RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t])];
 
 Plot[fun[func, t], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
  FrameTicks -> fRDticks], {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 
   3 -> "q"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 3, 20, 0.2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, \[Rho], a0}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. One last question- is it possible to scale the y axis of `a` and `q` only, such that it is in `au` i.e. divide all ticks by `au`? When I attempt this, the `e` y axis scales with it, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

To change units according to the selection, we use the same trick as above. We define a function `scale` that returns the appropriate scale factor:

```
Manipulate[
 fun[sel_, t_] := 
  Switch[sel, 1, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
   RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t], 3, 
   RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][
     t] (1 - RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t])];
 scale[sel_] := Switch[sel, 1 | 3, au, 2, 1];
 
 Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
  FrameTicks -> fRDticks], {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 
   3 -> "q"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 3, 20, 0.2, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, \[Rho], a0}]
```